# How to avoid loading email's content using spring integration mail

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I am using spring integration mail (5.3.1 release)
I have a flow:

```
    IntegrationFlows
    .from(Mail
        .imapIdleAdapter(imapAdapter)
    )
    .filter()
    .filter()
    ...
    .filter()
    .handle(service1)
    .get();
```

I want an email content to be loaded in service1.
I don't want to load email's content until it passes all filters.
My filters need to know only email headers.

I tried to use DefaultMailHeaderMapper but email's content is loaded anyway. I can see it in logs using "mail.debug"=true.

I was debugging and according to source of AbstractMailReceiver#receive, MimeMessage's content will be always loaded because e.g new IntegrationMimeMessage() uses MimeMessage(MimeMessage message) constructor that loads a content.

Is there any way to configure mail adapter to not load an email's content?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound. Especially this part:

> tarting with version 5.2, the autoCloseFolder option is provided on the mail receiver. Setting it to false doesn’t close the folder automatically after a fetch, but instead an IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE header (see MessageHeaderAccessor API for more information) is populated into every message to producer from the channel adapter.

And then take a look into the next section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#mail-mapping

So, to avoid eager content loading you should abandon the header mapper and don't close the folder automatically. This way the whole `MimeMessage` is sent as a payload. You probably won't be able to perform your filtering logic against headers because the content of the message is not fetched therefore we don't know what headers are there in `MimeMessage`. However you can try to get access to them from your filters, but already against the payload - not headers.

Comment: thank you for your feedback! But if I abandon header mapper (this.headerMapper == null) then AbstractMailReceiver#searchAndFilterMessages loads it. It calls AbstractMailReceiver#postProcessFilteredMessages running MimeMessage mimeMessage = new IntegrationMimeMessage((MimeMessage) filteredMessages[i]) (it loads the content);. Do you know if there is any another option to avoid eager content loading?

Comment: Hm. I see. So, we load it independently of the configuration. Probably we should consider to not load when `autoCloseFolder == false` and no `headerMapper`...

Comment: Can you please tell me where I can create a request for proposal on improvement of it? (if it is possible)

Comment: Yep! Here it is: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues !

Comment: I created an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3356